# Didn't receive the full message in TCP server-client

Tags: c#, server, client, tcplistener, issue-tracking

When I get data on server app then it is half sometime and most of the time I get the full message I don't know how to fix this (because from client app, I add products in cart and in server app I show those products that are added in cart in client app so after 10-15 product added when I add a new product then I get half I tried to get it fixed because in this scenario when I get the half message I will not be able to see that product in server app, only able to see when I add 2-3 more products after that and that half message product will show in list too).

I tried to accumulate message but not working.

What is the issue in my code?

```
byte[] remainingData;
private StringBuilder receivedMessage = new StringBuilder();
protected override void OnReceived(byte[] buffer, long offset, long size)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, (int)offset, (int)size);
            //var message = BinaryProtocol.DecodeMessage(buffer,ref remainingData);
            // Append the chunk to the accumulated message
            receivedMessage.Append(message);

            // Check if the accumulated message contains a complete message
            while (TryGetCompleteMessage(out string completeMessage))
            {
                await ProcessMessage(completeMessage);
                // Process the complete message
                messageQueue.Add(completeMessage);
                receivedMessage = new StringBuilder();
            }
            if (receivedMessage.Length > 0)
            {
                // Do something with incomplete message, e.g., log or process partially received data
                Debug.WriteLine("Incomplete message: " + receivedMessage.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error processing received data: {ex.Message}");
            DependencyService.Get<ToastService>().ShowSnackBar($"Error processing received data: {ex.Message}");
        }
    });
}
private bool  TryGetCompleteMessage(out string completeMessage)
{
    completeMessage = null;

    // Check if the accumulated message contains a newline character
    int newlineIndex = receivedMessage.ToString().IndexOf('\n');
    if (newlineIndex >= 0)
    {
        int messageLength = newlineIndex + 1;
        // Extract the complete message up to the newline character
        completeMessage = receivedMessage.ToString(0, newlineIndex);

        // Remove the processed message from the accumulated data
        receivedMessage.Remove(0, messageLength);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did AI write this? There are several potential problems: the buffer may contain bytes that aren't a complete UTF8 string, and Task.Run is used with some suspicious member variable access.

Comment: Why would you expect to receive complete messages, only? TCP is not message-based, it is stream-based. _You_ need to detect message boundaries or use an established higher level protocol.

Comment: sorry i write the word message because i used the message variable, and i know we get stream, var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, (int)offset, (int)size); in this code when i debug in the here i sometime get the half data that i am sending from client, and you can read my full code how i tried to resolve it.thanks

Comment: You didn't resolve it. You treat it as an error. But it isn't. It is the expected behavior. Any left overs are probably the beginning of another message that is not yet completely received. So, you should maybe introduce a protocol that makes it easy to detect message boundaries and reconstruct them.

Comment: See @StephenCleary 's own blog on Message Framing https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html it's probably the most common error with TCP handling. Why are you reinventing your own protocol anyway, why not just use an existing protocol such as gRPC or SignalR?

Comment: @StephenCleary can you please tell me what am i doing wrong in my current code and how can improve this. sorry i am a new in this and learning

Comment: @zilonco: There's several comments already pointing out different issues; have you tried fixing those? TCP socket protocols take a lot of time to learn to do correctly (and ChatGPT is terrible at them).